# Using __call in parent/base class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, call

I'm setting up some classes that have a common base class. In each class I have a bunch of functions that I access through the `__call` method.

```
class Test
{
    private function meth1()
    {

    }

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $args);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Since each function in the class for the most part just returns `$this` for method chaining I put the `return $this` into the `__call` method to avoid some redundancy.

Since I have a bunch of these classes that extend a `TestClass` I decided to move the `__call` method into that base class.

```
class BaseTest
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $args);

        return $this;
    }
}

class Test extends BaseTest
{
    private function meth1()
    {

    }
}
```

However when I move it into the base class I get a `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!` error.

Is there a way to do this in the base class or must each class have it's own `__call` method?

Also why does the nesting error occur?

Comment: Apart from the answer to this very question below, learn SOLID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because `private` method is not accessible in parent class.

Why would you want it to be private anyway?

So, to make it work either move `__call` to the extending class, or make the method `protected`.

By the way, do you really want to return `$this` from `__call`? You sure about that?

Comment: ya, you're right about returning $this in the first place, better to do it selectively.